# Best Way to check if a returned string value from a database is in the format "hh:mm:ss"

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting back ":" (no spaces), " : " (spaces on both sides), " :" (leading space) or ": " (trailing space) from some of the data im pulling from sql. I want to display date to the user only if its in the correct format "01:21:01". This will get put to a date picker set for time format. I have some code below, but it isn't working for me:

```
Dim D As Date
IF ds.Tables(0).Rows(1)("Pond1SampleTime").ToString() = "" Or Date.TryParseExact(ds.Tables(0).Rows(1)("Pond1SampleTime").ToString(), "hh:mm", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, D) Then
    Ponds1SampleTimePicker.Value = "1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM"
Else
    Ponds1SampleTimePicker.Value = SelDat + " " + ds.Tables(0).Rows(1)("Pond1SampleTime").ToString()
End If
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column "Pond1SampleTime" in the database?

Comment: If you use DateTime types rather than strings that look like dates, you dont have to worry about formats.  Also, you should set `Option Strict On` - the DTP Value property is DateTime and it wont let you assign a string to it.

Comment: @Steve - Varchar data type.  i migrated a bunch of data from AS400 database and it auto created this datatype and entered those different variations of ":" inputs i may have to delete all those out from every record and transfer to a temp table and re do the datatype to that column. :/

Comment: `TimeSpan.TryParse` is what you want in this case.

Comment: if this is a WinForm `DateTimePicker`, `.Value` is of type `DateTime` not String https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TimeSpan.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e(v=vs.110).aspx) if you only want to parse the hour, minutes and seconds of the string.

However, looking at your code you it looks like you are trying to parse a full date and set a date picker value. In this case append use DateTime.TryParse to try to parse the `selData + [your string]`

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan 
Dim d As Date
Dim hhmmss as string =ds.Tables(0).Rows(1)("Pond1SampleTime").ToString()
Dim ds as string = SelDat & " " & hhmmss

' Parse with TimeSpan
If TimeSpan.TryParse(hhmmss, ts) Then
    Ponds1SampleTimePicker.Value = ds
Else
    Ponds1SampleTimePicker.Value = "1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM"
End if

' Parse with DateTime
If DateTime.TryParse(ds, d) Then
    Ponds1SampleTimePicker.Value = ds
End if
```